# Foreach not returning if value not found

Tags: php, mysql

`foreach` seems to skip element if not found. Is there any way to force it to return a back up value if not found? I tried to use `coalesce` to no avail...it will return `period` if found, otherwise, skips it and move on to checking for next element.

```
$periods = ['October 2021', 'November 2021', 'December 2021'];

foreach ($periods as $k=>$p) {
     $test = $mysqli->query("select coalesce(period, '$p') as period, coalesce(match_date, 'not found') as match_date from table where period = '$p'");  
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($test)) {
       echo $row['period']. '-'. $row['match_date']. '<br>'  ;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: One way is you can ask it to tell you the number of rows returned in the query and act accordingly based on that

Comment: `foreach` doesn’t “skip”, you just aren’t accounting for the `while` loop not executing. You can just create a flag outside of the `while`, trigger the flag inside, and then outside the `while`, but before the end of the `for`, check the flag and handle a default: https://3v4l.org/nto2p

Comment: @ChrisHaas I get it know, it's the `while` that doesn't return not the `foreach`. I have no idea what you mean by creating a flag but I'll think about it. Thanks.

Comment: Here’s what a flag looks like: https://3v4l.org/B3nuv#v8.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way by creating first a table and inserting all the periods with a `foreach`

```
$reference = $mysqli->query("create temporary table reference (period varchar(15), match_date datetime); ");
foreach ($periods as $k=>$p) {
        $insert = $mysqli->query("insert into reference (period) 
        values ('$p')");
}
```

Then I use `left join` with `coalesce`

```
$reference2 = $mysqli->query("select ref.period as period, coalesce(tb.match_date, 'not found') as match_date 
FROM reference as ref 
LEFT JOIN table as tb
ON ref.period = tb.period");
```